# How do i set desired capabilities externally source (without hard coding);

Tags: frameworks, appium

```
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException,InterruptedException 
  {


    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 100000);
    capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "a1cc6f96");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question more. Provide source code which can be run by others to let them reproduce your error. Please prodive the full stack trace. Add more tags like Programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Create the **config.properties** file in the project. Add following data in the config.properties file

```
newCommandTimeout = 100000
browserName = chrome
platformVersion = 8.1.0
deviceName = a1cc6f96
platformName = Android
```

Then add the method that will return the property value

```
public class LoadProperty {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  InputStream input = null;

  public String getProperty (String propertyName){
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("path/to/config file/config.properties");
        prop.load(input);
        return prop.getProperty(propertyName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can use the property like following

```
LoadProperty prop =new LoadProperty();
String newCommandTimeout = prop.getProperty("newCommandTimeout");
String browserName = prop.getProperty("browserName");
String platformVersion = prop.getProperty("platformVersion");
String deviceName = prop.getProperty("deviceName");
String platformName = prop.getProperty("platformName");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", newCommandTimeout);
capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", browserName);
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platformName);
```

Comment: I tried to mark it as 1 but its not getting updated